# Concatenate elements from two lists into a third one in python

Tags: python, string, list, concatenation

```
a = ['1', '2', '3']
b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
c = []
```

What can I do to get the third list to be the concatenation of the corresponding elements from lists a and b, as in:

`c = ['1a', '2b', '3c']`

Comment: ``[x + y for x,y in zip(a, b)]``

Comment: Or using string formatting `f'{x}{y}'` in place of `x + y` in the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple `while` loop to do the trick:

```
a = ['1', '2', '3']
b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
c = []

counter = 0
while counter < len(a):
    c.append(a[counter] + b[counter])
    counter += 1

print(c)
```

Obviously, there are more elegant methods to do this, such as using the `zip` method:

```
a = ['1', '2', '3']
b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
c = [x + y for x,y in zip(a, b)]

print(c)
```

Both methods have the same output:

```
['1a', '2b', '3c']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a enumerate function to elegantly solve your problem.

```py
a = ['1', '2', '3']
b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
c = []
for idx, elem in enumerate(a):
  c.append(a[idx] + b[idx])
print(c)
```